# VS code extension for autoimport component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vscode-extensions, auto-import

I have same issue with auto import sfc component with Vetur extension and Nuxt

```
It perfect work with html template
```

[image]

```
Result
```

[image: Auto import complete]

```
Get nothing with pug template
```

[image]

Сan anyone help me get auto-import to work, because before that everything worked for me. I have only vetur pack installed

Comment: Please do not post code images, prefer text rather.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the closest issue related to your feature request is [this one](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/2572#issuecomment-972833809).
From what it looks, it is still not working as of today. I've posted a follow-up question with your query.
Feel free to subscribe to the issue for future updates.

TLDR: it is not supported **today** as far as I understand.